# Add value to each cell in range (Google apps script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im building a macro for google sheets, in which i iterate through a range and add a value to each cell. I've been trying a few different ways to do it, but they are all really slow. For 30 cells, this takes about a minute. Is there any way to make it faster/write it in a different way? This is a macro that will be run a lot of times in a day, for ranges of about 30 columns max.

```
for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {    
    if(range.getCell(1, j).getValue() == "") {
        range.getCell(1,j).setValue(valueToAdd/(colEnd-colStart));
    }   else range.getCell(1,j).setValue(valueToAdd/(colEnd-colStart)+(parseFloat(range.getCell(1,j).getValue()))); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function iterateThroughARange() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      vs[i][j]='Your Adjustment';
    });
  })
  rg.setValues(vs);
}
```

[Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

This way you get all of the data at one time perform you adjustment and save it all at one time.  It get's trickier if you want to avoid writing in certain cells.  Then you may have to go back to the slower method of writing to individual cells.  So Thinking about how how layout a spreads can impact the speed of your scripts quite a bit.

Comment: Luckilty, its always an entire range that gets altered, thanks! i'll test it now